# Manage Codeigniter Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I am still confused with codeigniter pagination. I make models and controller files like this:

My Model:

```
function getAllBooks($limit, $offset)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM books as b LEFT JOIN publishers as p ON b.publishers_id=p.publishers_id LEFT JOIN categories as c ON b.cat_id=c.cat_id ORDER BY books_id DESC LIMIT $limit, $offset");

    return $query;
}

function getCount($table)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
    return $query;
}
```

My Controller

```
public function page()
{
    $offset = '';
    if($this->uri->segment(3) == FALSE){
        $offset = 0;
    }else{
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }

    $limit = 3;

    $data['books'] = $this->model_front->getAllBooks($limit, $offset);
    $all_pages = $this->model_front->getCount('books');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'catalog/page/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $all_pages->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers']  = TRUE;

    ...

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    ....
}
```

The code runs successfully. But what confused me is as this scheme is happening:

```
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | // for main view
```

When I click the next button, the result is like this and so on:

```
Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 | // Second page
Item 4 | Item 5 | Item 6 | // Third page
Item 5 | Item 6 | Item 7 | // Fourth page
```

FYI, I have 10 records for testing and I want to display 3 records per page.
I still confused how to display 3 records per page like this:

```
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | // Main view
Item 4 | Item 5 | Item 6 | // Second page
Item 7 | Item 8 | Item 9 | // Third page
Item 10 | empty | empty | // Last page
```

Please advice me. I hope you understand the intent of my question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just confused with `$offset` and `$limit`. The first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

Use this code `$offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)-1) * $limit)` in `else` part, and then move up the variable `$limit = 3;` before if statement.

```
//Your code
$offset = '';
$limit = 3;
if($this->uri->segment(3) == FALSE){
    $offset = 0;
}else{
    $offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)-1) * $limit);
}
//Your code
```

**Use this query :**

```
SELECT * FROM books as b LEFT JOIN publishers as p ON b.publishers_id=p.publishers_id LEFT JOIN categories as c ON b.cat_id=c.cat_id ORDER BY books_id DESC LIMIT $offset,$limit
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM books as b LEFT JOIN publishers as p ON b.publishers_id=p.publishers_id LEFT JOIN categories as c ON b.cat_id=c.cat_id ORDER BY books_id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset;
```

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM books as b LEFT JOIN publishers as p ON b.publishers_id=p.publishers_id LEFT JOIN categories as c ON b.cat_id=c.cat_id ORDER BY books_id DESC LIMIT $limit, $offset
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I changed my query, but the result is still the same. My point is how to display (1, 2, 3 items) in main view, then (3, 4, 5 items) in next page.

Comment: run your query in phpmyadmin and watch which records are retrieved. post your modified query here.

Comment: It's look like this (1, 2, 3) for `LIMIT 0,3` then (3, 4, 5) for `LIMIT 3,3`. I change DESC to ASC just for simple purpose. Ok, but how to implement into codeigniter? As you can see, the `$offset` is defined by `$this->uri->segment(3)`

Comment: @life4learn do you want to show (1, 2, 3) and then (3, 4, 5) or (4,5,6)?

Comment: I have 10 records for example. I want to show 3 records per page, like this (1, 2, 3) <next> (4, 5, 6) <next> (7, 8, 9) and so on. Back to my code above, the result in my view is (1, 2, 3) <next> (3, 4, 5) <next> (4, 5, 6) till the last. The point that make me confused is what's wrong with my code or query?

Comment: Here is my 'books' table structure:

`books_id int (10)`
`publishers_id int(10)`
`cat_id int (10)`
`book_title varchar (255)`
.....

Then I join 3 tables (books, publishers, and categories). I think there is no problem with my table structure, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Just now I understand mistake use this in else part `$offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)-1) * $limit)` and move up `$limit = 3;` in before if statement.

Comment: Still the same. Do you mean I must write my Controller like this? `$limit = 3;`
`$offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)-1) * $limit;`
`if($this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE){`
`$offset = 0;`
`}else{`
`$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);`
`}`

Comment: Yeah, you're awesome. But let me say that your parentheses after `* $limit` makes error, so I remove it. Although I don't know why it didn't work when I use `$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);`, I want to say thank you very much @Manibharathi